# Wrong delimiter in Informatica output file

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have created a informatica workflow. The target is made as a flat file. The delimiter used is \037 with UTF-8 encoding, but the output file created contains **,** as the delimiter. It works fine with other WF's i have created.

How to get the required delimiter in the output file.

Regards
Sriram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check once if it is only \037 or ,\037 in delimiter. And also check the same in session in set file properties for the flat file target.

Comment: Thanks @EarlyBird. It worked. It had got changed to , in the set file properties. Once i changed it and ran its giving the proper delimiter in the flat file.